# Venn diagram event confusion

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

The green is clearly the $A \cap B$.

But what is **just** $A$ or **just** $B$

If I want to shade the **event** $A$, would it be:

[image]

**Does the event $A$** include the intersection as well?

Comment: Event $A$ will include the intersection.  If you were not to include the intersection that would be $A \cap B^c$ or $A$ and not $B$.  I think part of the problem comes from imprecise terminology.

Comment: Just $A$ or just $B$ is $(A-B) \cup (B-A).$ Is this what you ask?